# Deactivating AutoLinking in RTE editor - Typo3

Tags: ckeditor, yaml, typo3, typoscript, rte

Whenever a link is typed in the RTE editor, it will automatically be enclosed in an  tag and converted to a link.
Is there a way to stop this behavior, other than removing each link manually?

I'm not that much of an expert, but I tried to use the "minimal.yaml" configuration for the RTE editor, and It basically done what I wanted since the minimal setting doesn't have the linking option at all, but I need all the other options that are not available in the minimal, and I need the option to create a link manually when needed, just not automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a custom configuration file for the RTE. Follow this guide to do so : https://usetypo3.com/ckeditor.html

After that, in the `removePlugins` section, add `- autolinking` like this :

```
# Load default processing options
imports:
   ...
editor:
  config:
    ...

    removePlugins:
      - autolinking
```

Comment: The custom configuration file was already there, so I just added - autolinking underneath the other removed plugins, and it didn't work.
After some more search on the internet I found that some people where naming the plugin - autolink so I tried that as well, and again nothing changed.
Is there anything else needs to be done? I cleared the caches and everything.

Comment: Mmh ok, try not to include the core plugins by removing this line `- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }` and include the ones that you need manually.

Comment: Oh I didn't thought of that. it worked perfectly
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I did, I commented the lined where the autolinking.js actually creates a URL from the typed link and commented that out.

I don't think this is the optimal solution, but it's doing what it's supposed to.

/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Plugins/autolinking.js

```js
      editor.on('key', function(evt) {
        if (this.mode !== 'source') {
          if (evt.data.keyCode === spaceChar || evt.data.keyCode === tabChar || evt.data.keyCode === enterChar) {
            //editor.autolinking(evt);
          }
        }
```